# Application idle timeout - Want to implement autolock for a specific idle interval

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timer, python-idle

i want to implement auto lock for a specific idle time interval.

How can i increase iphone autolock idle time feature programmatically ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't increase or decrease the autolock idle time feature, it is controlled by the user from the settings menu. However you can enable or disable it by using the following code;

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```